# Set default shell binary location in Sublime Text 3

Tags: bash, sh, sublimetext3

I have installed bash 4.4.5 using `brew` on macOS Sierra, and use it as my primary shell. Due to SIP, I cannot simply upgrade/replace the built-in bash 3.2.57, so it's located in my `/usr/local/bin/` directory.

I have scripts in my `.bash_profile` that use bash 4.x features such as associative arrays. When I try to run any build process in Sublime Text 3, it is loading the system built-in bash instead of my custom installed bash, and spits our errors every time. Is there any setting or other way of changing which shell Sublime uses?

Might be useful:

```
$ which -a bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
/bin/bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0)
$ which -a sh
/usr/local/bin/sh
/bin/sh
$ sh --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0)
```

Comment: The file `Default\exec.py` that runs builds is hard-coded to use `/bin/bash` for MacOS and Linux. At first blush I think you'd have to override that file to point it at `/usr/local/bin/bash` instead. Another way to go might be to modify your `.bash_profile` so that it tests the value of e.g. `$BASH_VERSINFO` and skips anything bash 4 related.

Comment: Would there be anything I'd have to consider if I just changed that file?

Comment: If you override it, sublime will use your override even if the underlying file gets modified (in this case by a new release of Sublime Text) without warning you that it's happening. In that case if there were any bugs fixed or new features, you'd still be using the old version. As long as you're aware of that ramification, you should be OK.

Comment: As an aside there is a Sublime Package called OverrideAudit (disclosure: I wrote the thing) that checks for that situation when upgrades happen to help keep you in the loop: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/OverrideAudit

Comment: Wow, great. Thanks for your help, if you write this as an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec` command that is used to perform builds is contained in the `Default` package as `exec.py`, and is hard-coded to use `/bin/bash` to execute a process when using `shell_cmd` to specify the command.

There is no configuration option to switch that, so in order to get it to use a different version of bash you would need to create an override of the `Default/exec.py` file with the appropriate changes. The easiest way to do that is to use [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to open the file, then make changes and save it.

Although this will work, note that when a package override such as this exists, Sublime will exclusively use it in place of the file that it is replacing, even if the underlying file has been modified. In this case you don't get told and may be missing out on bug fixes or new features introduced by the package author.

You can mitigate this via [OverrideAudit](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/OverrideAudit) (disclosure: I'm the package author) which among other things will warn you if a package upgrade makes the timestamp on the underlying file newer than your override so that your attention will be drawn to it.

A less intrusive option would be to modify your `.bash_profile` to detect the version of bash in use and selectively skip commands that aren't compatible, but depending on what you're using in that file this may or may not be a viable solution.